# In what way can I order data by the calculated value in my mysql statement in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql

I want the mysql select statement order by $combine_count, but the $combine_count is calculate from this statement. Do you have any way to achieve my goal? Appreicate.

```js
$stm =$db->prepare("SELECT id , COUNT(user_id) as 'count'FROM sign   WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_10)");

 $term_0="$term[0]";
 $term_1="$term[1]";
 
 $stm->bindParam(":term_0", $term_0);
 $stm->bindParam(":term_1", $term_1);

 $stm->execute();

$rows = $stm->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $rows) {

    $count=$rows['count'];
  
 $count_percentage=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);
 $count_key_match=round(($count/$term_match_number)*100);
 $combine_count=round(($count_percentage+$count_key_match)/2); 
 
 echo $combine_count ; 
     
}//foreach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show where are `$term_match_number` and `$count_user_diff` coming from, but not from SQL for sure. So no, you cannot do this in this specific situation.

The best approach is not to echo directly, but sort array on the PHP side.

```
$array = array();
foreach ($rows as $rows) {

    $count=$rows['count'];

    $count_percentage=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);
    $count_key_match=round(($count/$term_match_number)*100);
    $combine_count=round(($count_percentage+$count_key_match)/2);   

    $array[] = $combine_count ; 

}
sort($array); // sorts ascending (low to high)
rsort($array); // sorts descending (high to low)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if MySQL will handle it but it's worth a try:

```
SELECT s.id, s.count
FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(user_id) as 'count' FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_0,:term_10) GROUP BY id) AS s
ORDER BY s.count
```